# HTML Post Methods Keeping User On Same Page

Tags: html, wordpress, http, post

I have researched every where for the answer to my question and can't get a straight answer from Goodle, nor does anyone else I have talked with have a clue.

I have a simple html form that posts a username and password to a url.  This is done within a WordPress website.  I want to keep the url page hidden from the users so that at no point they will ever see the page and be able to book mark it.

The code I have works fine and posts the information and the user is taken to a confirmation page.  However, the problem is that if the user inputs the wrong username or password, they are taken to the page I want to remain hidden.

I want to make the user to stay on the same page and have the error message be posted on the form page they are filling out.

Any direction as to how to do this would be greatful.  I've seen some close options with either Java Script, jQuery, or Ajax, but I am not too familiar with those.

What I currently have is below

```
<form action="http://anyurl.com" method="post" target="_blank">Username: <input type="text" name="user_name" />Password: <input type="password" name="password" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>Click on the submit button, and the input will be sent for verification of the test.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, passing by URL sounds a lot like `GET`, but I'll write this as a `POST` method. It sounds like an XHR (AJAX) Request, in this case via jQuery, would be you're best method:

```
// Bind to the form submit event
$("#your_form").on("submit", function (e) {
    // Prevent the form from performing default submit action
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get form contents (assuming username and password are the input names)
    var username = $(this).find('[name="username"]').val(),
        password = $(this).find('[name="password"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/processor.php",
        data: { username: username, password: password },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            // do whatever to check `data`
            // so if it passes it redirects to the success
            // page, and if it fails it will show a message
        },
        failure: function (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not too sure how to use this in WordPress.  I think it only allows html text, so when I pasted this in the text, it didn't produce anything.  I was going to make the changes necessary to fit my form but wanted to see if it would be accepted in the text side of the page.  It just showed the code in visual view rather than creating a form